# how to put "bolded" text into mysql base using php?

Tags: php, mysql

I wanted to know how i can put "bolded" text into mysql base using php?
Stachoverflow has that possibility, but can someone give me some tutorials, some links for learning, or some code for that
Thank u all.

Comment: [How to create Bold data in MySQL database text field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037903/how-to-create-bold-data-in-mysql-database-text-field)

Maby here is what you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML is string and you can save it to MySQL.

```
<form method='post'><textarea name='HTML'>This is &lt;b&gt;bolded&lt;/b&gt; text</textarea></form>
```